# How did the terms "leftmost" and "rightmost" (referring to generics) get their meaning?

Tags: java, generics, type-theory

Reading *[Angelika Langer's superb Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html)*, I'm finally starting to really grok some of the more subtle points of generics.

But I'm still hungup on some of the jargon. My layman's understanding of "***leftmost***" and "***rightmost***" is appararently different from how Langer uses it in *[her FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html)*.

> "*During that translation type erasure is performed, which means that
>   type parameters are replaced by their **leftmost** bound or Object if no
>   bound was specified..*"

...

> *"**Type Erasure**.* *The **leftmost** upper bound is used for type erasure and
>   replaces the type parameter in the byte code.  In our class Box {...} all occurrences of T would be replaced by the
>   upper bound Number .  For instance, if class Box has a private field
>   of type T and a method void set(T content) for setting this private
>   field, then the field would be of type Number after type erasure and
>   the method would be translated to a method void set(Number content)...*"

...

> "*The Type erasure of a type parameter is its **leftmost** bound...*"

Given `Box< T extends Number >`; my understanding is that `T` is the type parameter and `Number` is the bound. Then, since `Number` is to the ***right*** of the type parameter `T`, why isn't `Number` called "*the **rightmost** bound*"? Is this just a case of esoteric Mathemetician-speak? Is it like in formal type theory, six means nine and left means right?

Can somebody edumucate me on why something that is visually printed further to the right is called, "*leftmost*" in type theory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise against using that site. She conflates many terms in her own glossary. For example, she conflates instantiation and parameterization in her own glossary which contradicts the SE (this conflation is why you didn't understand how a parameterization can be an enclosing type as well). You should use the java SE because that's the official specification. Her website was an attempt to explain generics for those who are unable to grasp the java SE it appears, but her dumbing down of concepts is often very convoluted. You should instead take the time to understand the java SE.

Comment: Not even in the "Wild FJ" treatise on wildcards (which spurred to the incorporation of generics by java) are the words instantiation and parameterization used interchangeably. It is only her we site in which she defines her own terms; her reason for doing this is to simplify the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I suspect it's because it's possible to have more than one bound. [*Like this*](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html)?

> "...  The syntax for specification of type parameter bounds is:
>
> ```
> <TypeParameter extends Class & Interface 1 & ... & Interface N >
> ```
>
> A list of bounds consists of one class and/or several interfaces.
>
> Example (of type parameters with several bounds):
>
> ```
> class Pair<A extends Comparable<A> & Cloneable , 
>            B extends Comparable<B> & Cloneable > 
>   implements Comparable<Pair<A,B>>, Cloneable { ... }
> ```
>
> This is a generic class with two type arguments A and B , both of
>   which have two bounds. ..."

I can see how there would be a *leftmost* ***AND*** a *rightmost* bound in that case.

Comment: You may be right, because 4.4 of the JLS contains this phrase: "The order of types in a bound is only significant in that the erasure of a type variable is determined by the first type in its bound, and that a class type or type variable may only appear in the first position."  "leftmost" would mean "first".  It is not important which type appears last, and Langer doesn't use "rightmost" in the page you link to.